# Which US visa for interviews with citizens for a political book. B-1 (ESTA) or Media (I) or else?

Tags: visas, usa, esta

I am an independent German author who plans to write a book about politics and culture in the western world including the US and would like to go to the US to do interviews with regular citizens about their political opinions. I do not report about recent events. I do not interview politicians. I am not a journalist. I do not produce news and do not have any affiliation to a media company or a publisher. I have not published anything up to now. I would like to publish my book via self publishing in two years. Nobody inside or outside the US pays me for this. I will just sell the book someday.

I had some hopes that my activity qualifies as "independent research" which is allowed under B-1 (ESTA) regulations. But this term seems to be applicable to academic research only and not to my kind of investigation. An immigration officer might consider my activity not as "business" nor as "independent research" but as "media work" in so far as it is connected to the political field and distantly related to news gathering. But I cannot apply for a Media (I) Visa because only journalists who have a press card, credentials of or contract with a media company and membership to a professional journalistic association can apply. It seems to me that there is no US visa for my activity. B-1 (ESTA) seems insufficient and the road to Media(I) is closed. I appreciate your opinion about my case. Thank you.

Comment: Applying for a B-1 visa, togeather with a cover letter with the details expressed in your first paragraph (plus the statement a Media (I) Visa is not being applied for since you have no media card), would show that you are being very *straitforward* to the US authorities about your intensions to avoid misunderstandings. An Immigration Official would then *hesitate* to override this and refuse entry for any reason that was given in the cover letter. If possible, send the letter with the application so that it has been read before any Interview has been made.

Comment: Are you being compensated by your interviewees, or are you paying for your trip yourself?

Comment: My guess is that research for a book counts as independent research.  The examples given to clarify the meaning of the term "independent" focus on academic research because some academic research doesn't qualify as independent, so it's important for academic researchers to be able to determine whether their planned research counts as independent for the purposes of immigration law.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark Johnson, Crazymoomin and phoog for your answers. That helps a lot. Crazymoomin: I am not compensated by my interviewees or anybody else.  I may compensate interviewees if I dont find enough otherwise. I pay for all expenses. It is my project, financially, technically and with regards to content. No other institution, no university, no publisher is involved.

Comment: That you are not being compensated by your interviewees, should also be in the cover letter.

Comment: B-1 or ESTA (VWP)? Mark Johnson recommended applying for B-1 to have a decision for my case before entry. I would like to follow his recommendation. But a friend and frequent traveller to the US gave me the advice to go on ESTA (VWP), because immigration officers, as he sad, would not care so much about visa by a different branch of goverment in borderline cases like mine and could even feel pressed by a B-1 as it interferes with their free decision. What do you think about this objection? I thank you for your opinion.

Comment: I don't think much about that advice. Who does he think issues the visas **required** by some nationals before a final decision to allow entry by an IO is made? A further argument is that should you run into a random check **inside** the US, they can check your story since the visa application would contain the cover letter (or a reference to it).